# How to prove $\lim_{\mathbf{Re}z\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal{L}f(z) = 0?$

Tags: laplace-transform

consider $f\in L^1(R_+)$
and define Laplace transform
$$\mathcal{L}f(z):=\int_0^{\infty} f(s)e^{-zs}\mathbb{d}s. $$

How can I prove $$\lim_{\mathbf{Re}z\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal{L}f(z) = 0?$$

Intuitively it is obvious, but without exponential property I can't figure out how to tackle it.

Comment: Have you tried the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @sos440 let $g_n = f(s)\cdot e^{-ns}$? it sems not working.

Comment: Note that the family $\{ f(s)e^{-zs}:\Re(z)>0\}$ is dominated by an integrable function $|f(s)|$.

Comment: @sos440 Yes. My question is how to show $g_n$'s pointwise limit is 0? since $f\in L^1$.